# How do I make my entire game window transparent?

Tags: c#, xna

I’m working on a little overlay for Diablo 3 (For personal use only!) 
I want just to draw a Text string (We’ll see later for font) in the middle of the screen. 
But with XNA I cannot find how to put background to transparent…
My code so far is :

```
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, this.TestToShow, new Vector2(23, 23), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

So I only need 1 thing: make this black transparent!

Comment: Not a duplicate.
The linked question aims to entirely hide the window while this one aims to display text without hiding what is behind the window's background.

Comment: If you are trying to make something transparent with the help of a color in xna, the last component should be 0.
The value '255' as you used would be the equivalent of fully opaque.
This wont help though since you don't have control of the window's opacity in xna, and even if you had, it would probably be one single opacity for the entire window.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: I've tried this with VS 2010 and 2012, XNA 4.0. I can' t get the game window transparent. I hope someone else can as this is a really interesting question. Changing the alpha in the Color param at GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color) has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You do not seem to understand what `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color)` does.
XNA opens a Windows Window and draws with DirectX into it.

`GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color)` clears the buffer drawn with DirectX, but doesn't have anything to do with the window.
To make the window transparent, you have to modify the underlaying window.

To do that you have to first add references to System.WIndows.Forms and System.Drawing.

In the Constructor of your Game1 class, you do the following:

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    IntPtr hWnd = Window.Handle;
    System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
    System.Windows.Forms.Form form = ctrl.FindForm();
    form.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
```

Let's go through this line by line:

Well, the first two are auto generated and we don't care about these.

```
IntPtr hWnd = Window.Handle;
```

This line gets you the pointer to the underlaying Window that is registered in Windows.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
```

This line gets the WindowsForms-`Control` in the given Window.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = ctrl.FindForm();
```

This line gets you the Form to which the Control belongs to.

```
form.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

This last line sets the key-`Color`, that identifies one single `Color`-value to not be drawn at all. I used `Black`, but you could also choose `CornflowerBlue`.

This makes your window internally transparent for that `Color`. I suggest you should choose the same `Color` as your clear-`Color`.

Two things to note:

1. Best practice is to cache your `Form` so you can set the `TransparencyKey` from anywhere.
2. You can also make your `Window` borderless this way:

`form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;`

Hope I could help.

Edit:
I just realized this was asked years ago and had no answer. So feel free to use this, if you stumble upon it.

Comment: A little late, but basically that (or close) was I ended up doing.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd); always returns null ?